# How to retrieve one particular number form text with multiple numeric values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to extract some information from a SMS message text. I have SMS text in a column. Example of of SMS message text is give from.

[SMS Text Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oghd.png)

From this column I want to extract only amount information. I just want to extract amount only which is followed by NPR in above example.

Please Suggest

Comment: which particular number you want select

Comment: Is there a constant structure to the text?  Usually, this can be done by location, if the sentence is a constant and the sum is always in a specific index within the text.  For instance, spaces or padding.

Comment: check substring function

Comment: Yes of course it is possible but what are you really asking? In which context do you want to do it, in a query or a procedure? Is there a repeatable pattern to the text you want to extract from like "credited by" or similar?

Comment: Two steps: **1)** Find an algorithm. (the number between 'NPR' and 'on'? the number that has both a comma and a point? The first number after 'credited'? ...) **2)** Write a query. Which of the two are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below: though it will work only for this case and this string:

```
select substring('Your account 18715240300738 has been credited by NPR 20,784.00 on Apr  4 2016  1:30PM REF: BH691241S6807782849 Thank you',
charINDEX('NPR','Your account 18715240300738 has been credited by NPR 20,784.00 on Apr  4 2016  1:30PM REF: BH691241S6807782849 Thank you')+4,10)
```

Comment: Why hard code 10 when you can use same idea to find how many characters to extract?

Comment: yes, i've used only for this particular case